# URL.Action does not send data to method correctly

Tags: url.action

I have this call to MyMethod that sends w,h, and id. However, h is always null, even if I change the name. w and id have values. Any idea what is going on?

showDialog('@Url.Action("MyMethod", "MyController",new { w = "300", h = "800", id = "testing" })', "800", "500", "Popup Title", null, callBack);

public ActionResult MyMethod(string w, string h, string id)
{

}

Comment: It is not good to keep numbers in string.

Answer (score 0):

Although this does not couse your troubles, numerics should be kept in a numeric type, try this:

```
showDialog('@Url.Action("MyMethod", "MyController",new { w = 300, h = 800, id = "testing" })', "800", "500", "Popup Title", null, callBack);

public ActionResult MyMethod(int w, int h, string id) {

}
```

Comment: But why would one parameter not get the value?

Comment: did you check the data in the POST ? in firebug or something? when you go to tab 'NET' you can see xhr requests there, check what data you are posting to the server